# Express, node is inserting duplicate values in my tablee

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My code is inserting duplicate values in my mysql table like de image below:
I have a map function which returns my treated array values like this array in console:
[[0,1,2,"ENPG6ViT1w"],[0,1,3,"ENPG6ViT1w"]]

If i run this query, it insert only 2 rows in my table which is the right behavior:

INSERT into sales (idSales, quantidade, idStockProduct, idSale) VALUES (0,1,2,"RWQt9x1e4l"), (0,1,3,"RWQt9x1e4l")

but my code is inserting 4 rows like image below:
[image]

this is my code:

```
async function saleInsert(values) {

    try {
        let idSales = 0
        let quantidade = -1
        const teste = await values[0].map(obj => [idSales, 1, obj.idStock, idSale]);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(teste))

        const query = 'INSERT into sales (idSales, quantidade, idStockProduct, idSale) VALUES ?'
        const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            conn.query(query, [teste], (error, results, fields) => {
                if (error) return reject(error);
                return resolve(results);
            });
        })

        const updateTableStock = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            conn.query('update stock set  quantidade = quantidade ?  where idStock = ?', [quantidade, teste.idStock], (error, results, fields) => {
                if (error) return reject(error);
                return resolve(results);
            })
        })
        console.log(`update stock table ${updateTableStock}`)
        let tratado = JSON.stringify(result)
        return tratado
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

}
```

the nodemon console seems to duplicate the insert like this:

```
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/server.js`
app listening on port 8080
Connection established!
insert Sale
values insert sales [[{"idStock":2,"nome":"Produto 1","preco":2,"quantidade":-6},{"idStock":3,"nome":"produto 2","preco":1,"quantidade":10}]]
[[0,1,2,"ENPG6ViT1w"],[0,1,3,"ENPG6ViT1w"]]
update stock table [object Object]
insert Sale
values insert sales [[{"idStock":2,"nome":"Produto 1","preco":2,"quantidade":-6},{"idStock":3,"nome":"produto 2","preco":1,"quantidade":10}]]
[[0,1,2,"ENPG6ViT1w"],[0,1,3,"ENPG6ViT1w"]]
update stock table [object Object]
```

why this code is duplicatin my table?
any idea would be of great help!! THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **saleInsert()** function seems well.
you should check where the **saleInsert() function** is being called and make sure it's only being called once.

And you should check if there are any triggers in the tools you use that cause the double insert

Comment: Thanks,i was just looking for previously events before node calls, and found that in my services files i put a for loop. Because i was trying to double or bulk insert in node.

Comment: my code in service file is just like this: so i just cut off the for look

export const closeFinalSaleService = async (...props: any) => {
    const uri = `${uriRelative}admin/sale/products/sale`
    for (let i = 0; i < props[0].length; i++) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                uri, {
                method: 'PUT',

Comment: Wow, glad to hear your problem is solved!